# Use regular expressions to extract PHP variable names from blade template?

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract php variables from Blade templates. The issue is that I can't figure out how to exclude variables created within foreach loops.

```
{{ $ok }}
{{$alsoOK}}
@foreach($yes as $no)
{{ $no }}
{{ $no->foo }}
{{ $a[$b] }}
{{ func($x, $y) }}
@endforeach
{{ "$t" }}
{{ ${oij} }}
{{ $$p }}
```

So for the above code, I'd like to extract:

```
$ok
$alsoOK
$yes
$a
$b
$x
$y
$t
$oij
$p
```

but don't extract `$no` or `$foo`.

My regex is failing me and I can't quite tell why.

`~[\({][\s]?(\$[A-Za-z0-9_]*)[\s]?[\)}]?~img` almost does it, but it also captures the first `$no` after the foreach loop.

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: What about `{{ $x[$y] }}`? or `{{ func($x, $y) }}`?

Comment: It is tricky to filter out local variables. How did you land up in this situation?

Comment: It's for a GUI that does a side by side preview of a blade template code and the display. All variables need to be sent to the compiler, so they must be extracted from the template.

Comment: @qotsa42 Ok, so you wish to show the preview of the output of the blade template code being written by the end user?

Comment: @nick You're right, these cases should be added to the tests.

Comment: @nice_dev that is correct. The templates themselves are stored in the DB instead of as a static file.

Comment: Also, what about values in strings e.g. `{{ "${x}4" }}` or variable variables `{{ $$x }}`?

Comment: Right you are again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got a solution, based on Marcin's answer above.

It loops through each line of the template. However, it does not ignore foreach lines completely.

Instead, when it encounters the foreach directive, it will extract the first variable (I'm calling it the `iterable`) and then it adds the next variables, `$key` and possible `$value`, to and ignored list. The ignored variables are then filtered out of the final list.

```php
<?php

$template = <<<TEMPLATE
{{     \$ok }}
{{\$alsoOK}}
@foreach(\$yes as \$no)
{{ \$no }}
{{ \$no->foo }}
{{ \$x[\$y] }}
{{ func(\$a, \$b) }}
@endforeach
@foreach(\$iterable as \$key => \$value)
{{ \$key }} {{ \$value }}
@endforeach
@foreach(\$iterable2 as \$value2)
{{ \$value }}
@endforeach
{{ "\$t" }} 
{{\$\$p}}
{{ \${abc} }}
TEMPLATE;

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $template);
$variables = [];
$ignored = [];

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/@foreach\((.+?)\)/', $line, $matches)) {
        preg_match_all('/\\$([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/', $line, $foreachVars);

        // Add the first variable (iterable) to the final variable list
        $variables[] = $foreachVars[1][0];

        // Add subsequent variables (key/value) to the ignored list
        $ignored = array_merge($ignored, array_slice($foreachVars[1], 1));
    }

    // Extract variables, including quoted variables, variable variables, and variables with curly braces
    preg_match_all('/\\$({[^\}]*}|[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|"[^"]*")/', $line, $matches);
    $matches[1] = array_map(function ($match) {
        // Remove curly braces from the matched variable
        return preg_replace('/^\{(.+)\}$/', '$1', $match);
    }, $matches[1]);
    $variables = array_merge($variables, $matches[1]);
}

// Remove ignored variables
$variables = array_diff($variables, $ignored);

// Remove duplicates and sort
$variables = array_unique($variables);

// Print variables
foreach ($variables as $variable) {
    echo $variable . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will print:

```
ok
alsoOK
yes
x
y
a
b
iterable
iterable2
t
p
abc
```

Noticeably absent are the `$no`, `$key`, and `$value` parts of the `@foreach` directives.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is the same as `\w`.  A `}` inside of a character class does not need to be escaped.  Why not `$variables[] = array_shift($foreachVars[1]);` then `array_push($ignored, ...$foreachVars[1]);`?  `preg_replace()` works just fine on an array: `array_push($variables, ...preg_replace('/^\{(.+)}$/', '$1', $matches[1]));`.

Answer (score 0):

As I already said - regexp is the right tool for the job here. I prefer this approach - it's simpler and easier to maintain.

```php
<?php
$template = <<<EOT
{{     \$ok }}
{{\$alsoOK}}
@foreach(\$yes as \$no)
{{ \$no }}
{{ \$no->foo }}
@endforeach
EOT;

$lines = explode("\n", $template);

$variables = [];
$inForeach = false;

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  if (!$inForeach && preg_match_all('/\{{2}\s*\$([a-z\d_]+)\s*\}{2}/i', $line, $matches)) {
    $variables = array_merge($variables, $matches[1]);
  } elseif (preg_match('/@foreach\(\$([a-z\d_]+)\s+as\s+\$([a-z\d_]+)\)/i', $line, $matches)) {
    $inForeach = true;
    $variables[] = $matches[1];
  } elseif (preg_match('/@endforeach/i', $line)) {
    $inForeach = false;
  }
}

$variables = array_unique($variables);

print_r($variables);
```

harvests all the variables, but ignores those within `@foreach` block:

```php
Array
(
   [0] => ok
   [1] => alsoOK
   [2] => yes
)
```

Comment: So this should yield `$yes` but not `$no`. Your solution matches `$no`. I'd like to use regex only but I'm open to other approaches. Maybe make a copy of the text and delete everything between the foreach loops and manage those separately?

Comment: This is really close, but it should also match `$yes`, as that is a user-defined variable. I've edited the test case with some additional examples that also need to match.

Comment: `/[a-z\d_]/i` is more simply written as `/\w/`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest iterating over each line of the template and only extract the variables of each line.
This way you could easily skip those lines, that appear within a foreach loop.

Another advantage of this approach would be writing better readable and maintainable code.

Comment: Hi, it's better to provide a runnable example

Comment: @pierpy Thanks for your feedback. Are there some written guidelines, where I can read more about that?

Comment: Your approach is well suited for answering homework questions, read [meta here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) . Your answer fits better as an helpful comment! Docs for answering are here: [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)